# React - Displaying Data from API

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to consume an API and display it on my app. It is currently pulling in the data in the console log but I can't seem to access it to display it on my app as it is just stuck on loading... I want to show the data with the number of confirmed cases on the h5 variant of the first card {confirmed.value} But not to sure why it is not showing.

Cards

```
import React from 'react'
import {Card, CardContent, Typography, Grid} from '@material-ui/core'
import styles from './Cards.module.css'



export default function Cards({data: {confirmed, recovered, deaths}}){


    if(!confirmed){
        return`Loading...`


    }


    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Grid container spacing={3} justify="center">
            <Grid item component={Card}>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>Infected</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="h5">{confirmed.value}</Typography>
                    <Typography color="textSecondary">REAL DATE</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2">Number of active cases of COVID-19</Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container spacing={3} justify="center">
            <Grid item component={Card}>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>Recovered</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="h5">REAL DATA</Typography>
                    <Typography color="textSecondary">REAL DATE</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2">Number of Recovered cases of COVID-19</Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container spacing={3} justify="center">
            <Grid item component={Card}>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>Deaths</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="h5">REAL DATA</Typography>
                    <Typography color="textSecondary">REAL DATE</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2">Number of Death cases of COVID-19</Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </div>
    )
}
```

App JS

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import {Cards, Chart, CountryPicker} from './components'
import styles from './App.module.css'
import {fetchData} from './api'


export default class App extends Component {
    state = {
        data: {},
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        const fetchedData = await fetchData()
    console.log(fetchedData);

    this.setState({data: fetchedData})


    }

    render() {

        const {data} = this.state;

        return (
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <Cards data={data} />
                <CountryPicker/>
                <Chart/>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your `Cards` component doesn't consume a `data` prop. What is `data` supposed to map to?

Comment: Thanks I just added the data prop however I am getting a typeError now Cannot read property of 'confirmed' of undefined...Code has been updated

Comment: Can you confirm the shape of `fetchData`? Does it nest `confirmed`, `recovered`, and `deaths` properties deeper?

Comment: I just updated the code for you and I believe it does, maybe I am accessing it incorrectly?

Comment: That all appears to be correct. Is it possible to get a minified and reproducible demo up in a codesandbox?

Comment: Trying to do it now, not to sure what is going on here though...https://5lew7.codesandbox.io/

Comment: Can you link the actual sandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-yonath-5lew7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The data seems to exist and load when I comment out `CountryPicker` and `Chart`. https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-bush-ohe95?file=/src/components/Cards/Cards.js Would need to dig in further to see why one or both of those components make `App` not work.

Comment: Hmm, thats odd. Do you know why it works when you comment them out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211673/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-hellol).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the component header to:

`export default function Cards({confirmed, recovered, deaths})`

Comment: Thats what I originally had before which did not work. I passed a data prop to the Card component

Comment: can you `console.log(data)` after `const {data} = this.state;` in `Cards` component and see what it gives ?

Comment: Yeah sure, I got the data object returned above which has been edited in my code

Comment: I can't really tell what's wrong unless you give more code. What is value of `confirmed` if you console.log it ?

Comment: from fetch data 
{confirmed: {…}, recovered: {…}, deaths: {…}, lastUpdate: "2020-04-14T23:41:11.000Z"}
confirmed: {value: 1973715, detail: "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/confirmed"}
recovered: {value: 474261, detail: "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/recovered"}
deaths: {value: 125910, detail: "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/deaths"}
lastUpdate: "2020-04-14T23:41:11.000Z"
__proto__: Object